# Strings and high memory usage

Tags: delphi

When I run this code in XE4, the application ends up using ~800 MB.

Why not closer to 100 MB ?

Using Ansistring instead of string makes no difference.

```
const
  N = 10000000; // 10 million
  M = 10;
var
  i,j: integer;
  s: string;
  X: array of string;
begin
  setlength(X,N);
  for i:= 1 to N do
  begin
    s:= '';
    for j:= 1 to M do s:= s+chr(65+random(25));
    X[i-1]:= s;
  end;
  showmessage('pause');
end;
```

Comment: My guess would be memory fragmentation... but it's really only a guess.

Comment: Yes, replacing s:= s+ with s[j]:= brings it down to 420 MB, but still a lot is wasted.

Comment: What if you do `X: Array of Array[1..10] of Char`? Does it gets any better?

Comment: Heavy usage of string concatenation like s := s + ... this is rather "heap mixer" than a program ;-)

Comment: You're badly fragmenting memory, and the memory manager has to allocate a new, larger block every time it's previously allocated block becomes too small. As it can't tell you won't use that previous block again, it hangs on to it so it won't have to allocate again but can reuse it. You're compounding the process by using string concatenation, which means lots of little reallocations ever time you use `s := s + `. It would be much better if you posted a new question explaining what you're trying to do here in the first place; allocating an array of 10M 10-char strings seems silly.

Comment: Then I get 340 MB. With Ansichar I can get 270 MB. It still feels like a big difference and with array of char, you loose some of the ease of string-handling.

Comment: To Ken white: I'm trying to sort MANY up to 15 character long strings in memory. Stored in an array. OK?

Comment: A 10 character string in XE4 uses 34 Bytes of memory.

Comment: Seems like the overhead of strings is simply too big, when you have many. I may try with array of byte and do my own messing around.

Comment: @UffeKousgaard Your example code _does not make sense_ in your case: The **memory fragmentation**, that leads to the **heavy memory usage** is mostly caused by your effort to fill your random strings _(by concatenation which is not a smart way to handle strings anyways)_. If you would like to optimize your code for **memory usage** you first need to make a small app, that generates a file with the random content you need, then load it into the memory for testing.

Comment: Come on: That issue was fixed ages ago, in my first comment. Why keep beating a dead horse?

Comment: @UffeKousgaard If I were you, I wouldn't mess with an array anyways. I would try to use a (T)List, and add my strings as PWideChars. Sorting a list is ways faster than sorting an array, and a 10 character length string stored in a PWideChar only reserves 24 bytes of memory (28 if compiled against x64).

Comment: "MANY up to 15 character long strings in memory" that is "ShortString". If those 15 characters are of `AnsiChar` realm then your datatype is 16 bytes `string[15]`, to keep `WideChar` you would have to use `string[30]` type that takes 31 bytes. Then you can use XE4 features `class operator implicit (const from: DataType1): DataType2` for transparent conversion of those to usual strings when you would actively work with some of them before/after storing. Then also read about Advanced Records and about `record helper` (actually misnamed non-class type helpers)

Comment: @pf1957 actually not in this place. Since it is getting done with one and the same variable (not with many of those simultaneously) Heap Manager would end having 3-4 memory frames of different sides and would just remap the string to the next after the previous one became too short. It is redundant memory copying comparing with outright SetLength, but the heap stress is constant here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A string of length 10 in XE4 uses 34 Bytes of memory (see [DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Long_String_Types)). 20 Bytes for the content, 2 Bytes for the #0 terminator and 12 bytes management data.

Each array entry is a pointer to that kind of memory. Thus those 10 million strings in the array end up using 380 MB (340 for the strings and 40 for the array items) of memory at minimum.

Comment: Very good answer. If you just add the memory fragmentation due to successive string concatenations it should be self-contained for later visitors.

Comment: @GabrielF 11 characters is not to lead to noticeable fragmentation. Even under insane assumption that heap manager would allocate a whole megabyte for the string, and would move it to another megabyte slot after every character added - that is still one 11 megabytes added to the hundreds of MB in question. But actually i believe the string s would not ever get re-allocated in the internal loop. The fragmentation comes from storing N short strings, not from M=10 concatenatiosn on a very short string s

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm unsure I understand what you mean... but memory fragmentation is definitely the explanation to the other 400MiB of memory being used. If you check the first few comments on the question, you'll see OP has already confirmed this (and it has also been explained - e.g. KenWhite's comment).

Comment: @gabrielf fragmentation comes from having 100m short strings,  but it is not related to concatenation here. The concatenation in this question makes no fragmentation at all and even theoretically could not cause it here with the code given.  Again,  of cause fragmentation happens,  and my code was made explicitly to avoid it. But you above connected the fragmentation with chars concatenating loop,  and here it is totally unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const MaxString = 15; // you said so

type stringholder = record
  strict private 
     var Cell: string[ MaxString * SizeOf(Char) div SizeOf(AnsiChar) ];
     function GetUS: String; // in xe 4 that is a shortcut to UnicodeString actual type
     procedure SetUS(const US: string); 
  public
     property Value: string read GetUS write SetUS;
     class operator Implicit(const from: string): stringholder; inline;
     class operator Implicit(const from: stringholder): string; inline;
  end;

function stringholder.GetUS: String;
var i: integer;
begin
  i := Ord( Cell[0] );
  SetLength( Result, i div (SizeOf(Char) div SizeOf(AnsiChar)) );
  if i > 0 then
     Move( Cell[1], Result[1], i);
end;

procedure SetUS(const US: string);
var i: integer;
begin
  If US = '' then begin
     Cell := ''; // constant here, not US itself
     Exit;
  End;

  i := Length(US);
  If i > MaxString then raise EInvalidCast.Create('.....'+US);

  i := i * SizeOf(Char) div SizeOf(AnsiChar)
  Move( US[1], Cell[1], i );
  Cell(. 0 .) := AnsiChar(i);
end;

class operator stringholder.Implicit(const from: string): stringholder;
begin
  Result.Value := from;
end;

class operator stringholder.Implicit(const from: stringholder): string;
begin
  Result := from.Value;
end;


const
  N = 10000000; // 10 million
  M = 10;
var
  i,j: integer;
  s: string;
  X: array of stringholder;
begin
  setlength(X,N);
  for i:= 1 to N do
  begin
    s:= '';
    for j:= 1 to M do s:= s+chr(65+random(25));
    X(. i-1 .) := s;
  end;
  showmessage('pause');
end;
```